# accessing variables from main method in python idle

Tags: python, variables, program-entry-point

So I know if I create a python file with no main method declared and then I run it, I'm able to access the variables within that file from the idle, but if I do declare a main method, then I cannot access any variables from the idle after the main method has finished running.

Does anyone know if there's a workaround where I'm able to use methods in my python program, while also being able to access variables from within them in the idle?

Comment: This doesn't require a workaround so much as it requires a knowledge of [scope](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces).

Comment: You can use the drop-down menu in that page's top left corner to access [the 2.7 version](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces), which has the exact same text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare variable inside a method/function they are only in scope for the life of that method or function. You can't access them from outside. If you want some variable to be available to you declare it in the global space and then import like you would any other function/class.

**file1.py**

```
some_var = whatever

def foo():
    another_var = 42

def bar():
    return 42
```

**file2.py**

```
from file1 import some_var
```

Will give you acces to `some_var` however you will not be able to access `another_var` unless you return form your function and save like this

```
from file1 import bar

another_var = bar()
```

You can access variable in a function while the function is running by using the `pdb` library like so:

```
>>> def foo(x):
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()  # this is one of the rare times it's okay to import inside a function
    return x* 2

>>> foo(5)
> <pyshell#13>(3)foo()
(Pdb) x
5
(Pdb)
```

`pdb` is a very useful debugging tool. It will help you see what id happening inside of your functions should you start getting some weird output. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html)